# Forward slash in netmiko_send_command and netmiko_send_config gives syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, networking, netmiko

In my paloalto panos , when i try to send command "show interface ethernet 1/1" it gives me syntax error. Other commands without forward slashes however work. No its not a configuration mode issue as I have made sure i am in the correct configuration mode. The command also works when i configure it through paltoalto system directly. What am I missing here? Is there any special way I need to send the command?

The code i used is a simple sample code but here it is anyway:

```
output = nr.run(
    task=netmiko_send_config,
    config_commands=["exit", "show interface ethernet 1/1"]
        )

print_title("DEPLOYING AUTOMATED BASELINE CONFIGURATIONS")
print_result(output)
```